# Is there a way to add a counter to mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to add a counter to the documents that match my query.  E.g., 1st document has counter = 1, 2nd document has counter = 2, and so on.

Here's a snippet of the data:

```
"_id": ObjectId("5d1b9aea5c1dd54e8c773f42")
"timestamp":
    [ 
      "systemTimestamp":    2019-07-02T17:56:53.765+00:00
      "serverTimestamp":    0001-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
      "systemTimeZone":     "System.CurrentSystemTimeZone"
    ]
"urlData":
    [0]:
        "fullUrl":"https://imgur.com/gallery/EfaQnPY"

"UID":"00000-W3W6C42GWTRE960"
"safety": "safe"
```

My query (this is copied from the Compass UI):

```
$match: 
{
    $and: [{"UID": "00000-WVUCW3JW7OTHDVE"},
       {"timestamp.serverTimestamp": 
              {
               $gte:ISODate("2019-08-01T00:00"), 
               $lte:ISODate("2019-09-30T00:00")
               }}]
}

$unwind:
{
    path: "$urlData",
    includeArrayIndex: 'index'
}

$match:
{
    "index": 0
}

$project:
{
    _id: 0,
    date: { $dateToString: {
    format: "%Y-%m-%d",
    date: "$timestamp.serverTimestamp"}},
    safety: "$safety",
    url: "$urlData.fullUrl",
    UID: "$UID"
}
```

Is there any way to add something to $project to include a counter?

Comment: So what's the problem? The `index` should have the counter starting from `0`. Do you want it to start from `1`?

Comment: I just want the first element of the urlData array, that's why I have a match on index of 0. So, for each document, I'm extracting the first element of that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer is there in your question itself**. We can get the expected output if the output of the last pipeline is added into an array and again unwinded with the included index.

Let's say, I have the following data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d81c3b7a832f81a9e02337b"),
    "first" : "John",
    "last" : "Smith"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d81c3b7a832f81a9e02337c"),
    "first" : "Alice",
    "last" : "Johnson"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d81c3b7a832f81a9e02337d"),
    "first" : "Bob",
    "last" : "Williams"
}
```

On running the following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":null,
            "data":{
                $push:"$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:{
            "path":"$data",
            includeArrayIndex: 'counter'
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            "data.counter":{
                $sum:["$counter",1]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot:{
            "newRoot":"$data"
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Output would be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d81c3b7a832f81a9e02337b"),
    "first" : "John",
    "last" : "Smith",
    "counter" : 1
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d81c3b7a832f81a9e02337c"),
    "first" : "Alice",
    "last" : "Johnson",
    "counter" : 2
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d81c3b7a832f81a9e02337d"),
    "first" : "Bob",
    "last" : "Williams",
    "counter" : 3
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This did exactly what I needed.